# Oracle SQL Join using (+)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What I wanted is to convert this query into ***old way*** using **(+)**:

```
select * from tbla a
left join tblb b
on b.col = a.col
left join tblc c 
on c.col = a.col
```

I tried:

```
select * from tbla a, tblb b, tblc c 
where a.col(+) = b.col and a.col(+) = c.col;
```

But an error occured:

**ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table**

Comment: It's a restriction of this old-style syntax. But the point for me is: why do you want to do such a backward conversion?

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to stop using the ancient and proprietary `(+)` operator and suggest to move to an explicit `left join`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using + on the wrong table, try:

```
select *
  from tbla a, tblb b, tblc c 
  where a.col = b.col(+) and b.col = c.col(+);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it in this way:

```
select *
    from (select *
                  from tbla a
                         , tblb b
                 where a.col = b.col(+)
            ) a1
            , tblc c 
    where c.col(+) = a1.col;
```